# Finding Nth element in a list using For Loop

Tags: python

So imagine I want to find the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th element in another list.

```
position = [2,3,4]

Sample_List = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

The loop would give back the result:

```
['c','d','e']
```

Comment: `for i in position: print sample_list[i]` or `[sample_list[i] for i in position]`

Comment: `map(Sample_List.__getitem__, position)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
the_elements = [Sample_List[i] for i in position]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
elements = map(lambda k:Sample_List[k], position)
```

On python3 you need to convert it to a list

```
elements = list(map(lambda k:Sample_List[k], position))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> position = [2,3,4]
>>> Sample_List = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> itemgetter(*position)(Sample_List)
('c','d','e')
```